# Use of "comma", inside the quotation marks or after it?

Tags: american-english, punctuation, british-english, commas

I am having confusion, where to put comma, in the following case after the word **water**:

1. There are roughly 1000 different words for **“water,”** as well as for “louse”.

Or should I use put comma after quotation mark? As in:

1. There are roughly 1000 different words for **“water”,** as well as for “louse”.

Comment: If you want the answer to focus on BrE (per your comment below) , you need to add that tag.

Comment: @Cascabel, Okay, surely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In American English, commas and periods *always* go inside quotation marks. [See rule 4.](https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/quotes.asp)

Also:

[The American style places commas and periods inside the quotation marks, even if they are not in the original material. British style (more sensibly) places unquoted periods and commas outside the quotation marks. For all other punctuation, the British and American styles are in agreement: unless the punctuation is part of the quoted material, it goes outside the quotation marks.](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/british-versus-american-style.html)

Comment: Thanks! But do you know about BrE's rules for commas?

Comment: What is BrE? I am not familiar with this abbreviation.

Comment: British English...just as AmE is the abbreviation for American English.

Comment: Ah. I don't know what the rules are in British English, but I imagine they're the same. One difference I know of is that the British style uses single quotes for initial quotations, and then double quotes for quotations within the initial quotation.

Comment: @NathanM, please, add your comment of British English into your answer, so that I can re-accept it.

Comment: This site answers your question about British usage, Iqbal. http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/british-versus-american-style.html

Comment: I included an excerpt from this site in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Nathan, I am going to click the link what is inside.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of assistance.

Comment: Rather than saying that this is a rule of  American English, it might be better to say that this is the rule of the *style manuals*, such as the Chicago Manual of Style, that are in fact followed by most U.S. publishers. An organization based in the U.S. could adopt for its publications a style manual that prescribes that periods and commas be placed outside the quotation marks; that wouldn't be a violation of any general rule of the language.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at the link I posted in my answer. Who dictates grammar usage? The answer: Style guides such as the CMS and the MLA and the AP Stylebook and Garner’s Modern English Usage.