# Meaning and usage of "as well as"

Tags: meaning, phrases, context

We use "as well as" to mean "and in addition", "and also", but the following sentence completely made me confused:

> [There are roughly 1000 different words for “water,” as well as for “louse”.](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2015/10/one-thousand-different-words-water)

I know that above mentioned sentence should mean that "there are roughly 1000 different words for “water,” **and also** for “louse”.

Doesn't that mean that there are individually 1000 words for “water” and another 1000 words for “louse”? If so, then we have 2000 words. Please correct me if I am asking wrong.

Comment: This question might be better suited for https://www.ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'll second that both that and [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/456635/use-of-comma-inside-the-quotation-marks-or-after-it) should have been asked at the ELL stack.

Comment: Also, fwiw, there aren't actually 1000 words for water or lice.  [There are 850-odd New Guinean languages belonging to a few dozen language families, with a dozen or so isolates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_of_Papua_New_Guinea), so most of these "1000" words are going to be variant spellings or dialectical pronunciations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it means that there are 1000 words *each* for "water" and "louse", for a total of roughly 2000 words.  Consider it this way:

> There are roughly 1000 different words for “water,” as well as [*1000 words*] for “louse”.

The original version is simply a shortcut.

By the way, in math, this would be the ***[distributive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property)***:

> 1000 words (water + louse) = 1000 words (water) + 1000 words (louse)

Comment: I understand what you mean by your diagram, but it's still wildly misleading since 1000 words for "water and louse" is NOT 1000 words for "water" and 1000 more words for "louse". The part before that is golden, though.

Comment: There is a big difference between _...1000 words for water and louse_ and _1000 words for water and **for** louse_.   The former means that there is a total of 1000 words for [water and louse] together while the latter indicates that there are 1000 words each for water and for louse as two separate items.

Answer (score 3):

When someone says "as well as" it generally means "and in addition," which is the same thing as saying "and." Thus, "as well as for *louse*" is the same as saying "and for *louse*." See [Merriam-Webster's definition.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20well%20as)